# Changing text to an image in Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am learning jQuery and have a list of hotels with star ratings that I am getting from an Ajax call. I want to change the ratings that are in text to an image with stars but I cannot seem to do this.

If I run an if statement with each it only returns and runs the value of the first in the list which is say 4.5 to the rest in the result list so all result show 4.5 instead of their respective star rating

thanks

```
var jqxhr =  $.ajax({ 
            url: "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_AU&city=Sydney&stateProvinceCode=NW&countryCode=AU&_type=json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            callback: "hotelList"
            })
          .done(function(data) {
            var StrHotelListResponse = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;   
                $.each(StrHotelListResponse, function(index, value) {
                $('.target').append(value.name + '<span class="rating" data-exprating="'+value.hotelRating+'"></span><span>'+value.hotelRating+'</span><br />')
                });
                    if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '1') {
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star1.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '1.5'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star1-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '2'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star2.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '2.5'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star2-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '3'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star3.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '3.5'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star3-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '4'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star4.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '4.5'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star4-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if($('.rating').data('exprating') == '5'){
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/star5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else{
                                $('.rating').html('<img src="img/starnr.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
          })
          .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
          })
          .always(function() {
            //alert( "finished" );
          });

jqxhr.always(function() {
  //alert( "second finished" );
});
});
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: please share your html and the script you have tried?

Comment: Thanks, my code is probably very longhanded

Comment: Ok great, I was told in another post that you rarely should need to execute anything else inside a each loop, I guess he was talking abount another function?. thanks for your help

Comment: I have moved it inside but it still does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were executing the if/else statements outside of the loop so it only did it for the first one, you need to move them inside the loop and then check the value of the current item in the loop and then append to your target div.

```
var jqxhr =  $.ajax({ 
            url: "https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_AU&city=Sydney&stateProvinceCode=NW&countryCode=AU&_type=json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            callback: "hotelList"
            })
          .done(function(data) {
            var StrHotelListResponse = data.HotelListResponse.HotelList.HotelSummary;   
                $.each(StrHotelListResponse, function(index, value) {
                    $('.target').append(value.name + '<span class="rating" data-exprating="'+value.hotelRating+'"></span><span>'+value.hotelRating+'</span><br />')
                     if(value.hotelRating == '1') {
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star1.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '1.5'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star1-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '2'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star2.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '2.5'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star2-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '3'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star3.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '3.5'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star3-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '4'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star4.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '4.5'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star4-5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else if(value.hotelRating == '5'){
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/star5.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                            else{
                                $('.target').append('<img src="img/starnr.gif"  alt="Star rating" width="72" height="15"/>');
                            }
                });
          })
          .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
          })
          .always(function() {
            //alert( "finished" );
          });

jqxhr.always(function() {
  //alert( "second finished" );
});
});
```

Comment: Sorry you code works thanks